# .text is not a function - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get text of my `td` but I got this error: `$tds[2].text is not a function`.

the result of `console.log('td',$tds[2])` is :

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $trs = $('table > tbody > tr')
  // console.log('trs',$trs)

  var items = []
  for (var $i = 0; $i < $trs.length; ++$i) {
    $tds = $trs[$i].cells

    console.log('td', $tds[2].text())

    var item = {}
    item['label'] = ''
    item['flag'] = ''
    item['value'] = ''

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tmain" dir="rtl" width="90%" border="0" align="center" id="Table8">
  <tbody>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="mer_name" checked=""></td>
      <td>نام فروشگاه</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="terminal_id"></td>
      <td>کد ترمينال</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="terminal_name"></td>
      <td>نام ترمينال</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="log_date" checked=""></td>
      <td>تاريخ ارسال</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="log_time" checked=""></td>
      <td>زمان ارسال</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="getpoint_date" checked=""></td>
      <td>تاريخ خريد</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="getpoint_time" checked=""></td>
      <td>زمان خريد</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="card_id" checked=""></td>
      <td>شماره کارت</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="name_pr"></td>
      <td>نام دارنده کارت</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="device_type"></td>
      <td>نوع پنل</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="amount" checked=""></td>
      <td>مبلغ</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="currency_" checked=""></td>
      <td>واحد</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="point_rate" checked=""></td>
      <td>ضريب لويالتی</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="point_lo" checked=""></td>
      <td>امتياز</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="doc_type" checked=""></td>
      <td>نوع پرداخت</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="cheque_num"></td>
      <td>شماره چک</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="cheque_date"></td>
      <td>تاريخ چک</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="account_number"></td>
      <td>شماره حساب</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bank_type"></td>
      <td>نام بانک</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="branch_code"></td>
      <td>شعبه</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="approval_code"></td>
      <td>کد خريد اعتباری</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="rebate_cons_per" checked=""></td>
      <td>درصد کارمزد </td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="special_discount"></td>
      <td>درصد تخفيف</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="pos_setup_rebate"></td>
      <td>درصد کارمزد بانی POS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bin_setup_rebate"></td>
      <td width="33%">درصد کارمزد پشتيبان</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="merch_setup_rebate"></td>
      <td width="33%">درصد کارمزد بازارياب</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="merch_setup"></td>
      <td width="33%">بازارياب</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="mer_id">
      </td>
      <td>کد فروشگاه</td>

      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bin_code">
      </td>
      <td>کد پشتيبان</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bin_name"></td>
      <td>نام پشتيبان</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code post CODE in a [mcve] and use textContent for DOM nodes, `$("td",this).eq(2).text()` for a jQuery cell

Comment: `$tds[2]` returns the DOM node and not a jQuery object

Comment: Add the HTML to your post please so I can create the same code and fix it

Comment: @mplungjan that's console log

Comment: @JuniusL. I am fully aware of it. We want a snippet

Comment: added html code.

Comment: try `console.log('td', $($tds[2]).text())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$tds[2]` return `HTMLDom object`, to use jquery methods, it needs to be `Jquery` object. So wrap $tds[2] in with  `$()` like $($tds[2]).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $trs = $('table > tbody > tr')
  // console.log('trs',$trs)

  var items = []
  for (var $i = 0; $i < $trs.length; ++$i) {
    $tds = $trs[$i].cells
    
    //console.log('td', $tds[2].text())
    console.log('td', $($tds[2]).text())

    var item = {}
    item['label'] = ''
    item['flag'] = ''
    item['value'] = ''

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tmain" dir="rtl" width="90%" border="0" align="center" id="Table8">
  <tbody>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="mer_name" checked=""></td>
      <td>نام فروشگاه</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="terminal_id"></td>
      <td>کد ترمينال</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="terminal_name"></td>
      <td>نام ترمينال</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="log_date" checked=""></td>
      <td>تاريخ ارسال</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="log_time" checked=""></td>
      <td>زمان ارسال</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="getpoint_date" checked=""></td>
      <td>تاريخ خريد</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="getpoint_time" checked=""></td>
      <td>زمان خريد</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="card_id" checked=""></td>
      <td>شماره کارت</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="name_pr"></td>
      <td>نام دارنده کارت</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="device_type"></td>
      <td>نوع پنل</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="amount" checked=""></td>
      <td>مبلغ</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="currency_" checked=""></td>
      <td>واحد</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="point_rate" checked=""></td>
      <td>ضريب لويالتی</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="point_lo" checked=""></td>
      <td>امتياز</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="doc_type" checked=""></td>
      <td>نوع پرداخت</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="cheque_num"></td>
      <td>شماره چک</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="cheque_date"></td>
      <td>تاريخ چک</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="account_number"></td>
      <td>شماره حساب</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bank_type"></td>
      <td>نام بانک</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="branch_code"></td>
      <td>شعبه</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="approval_code"></td>
      <td>کد خريد اعتباری</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="rebate_cons_per" checked=""></td>
      <td>درصد کارمزد </td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="special_discount"></td>
      <td>درصد تخفيف</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="pos_setup_rebate"></td>
      <td>درصد کارمزد بانی POS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bin_setup_rebate"></td>
      <td width="33%">درصد کارمزد پشتيبان</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="merch_setup_rebate"></td>
      <td width="33%">درصد کارمزد بازارياب</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="merch_setup"></td>
      <td width="33%">بازارياب</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="mer_id">
      </td>
      <td>کد فروشگاه</td>

      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bin_code">
      </td>
      <td>کد پشتيبان</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bin_name"></td>
      <td>نام پشتيبان</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Andreas is correct.
Change the object to a jQuery object like this.

```
 $tds = $($trs[$i].cells);
```

Or (maybe too inefficient)..

```
console.log('td',$($tds[2]).text());
```

Or use plain js

```
console.log('td',$tds[2].innerText);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Answer (score 0):

Use textContent for DOM nodes, `$("td",this).eq(2).text()` for a jQuery cell

Here is how to do it with jQuery. It is not recommended to mix DOM and jQuery the way you did for the obvious reason that you will get confused and use the wrong access method

```js
$(function() {
  var items = []
  $('table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    var thirdCell = $("td", this).eq(2).text()
    items.push({
      "whatever": thirdCell,
      'label': '',
      'flag': '',
      'value': ''
    })
  })

  console.log(items)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tmain" dir="rtl" width="90%" border="0" align="center" id="Table8">
  <tbody>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="mer_name" checked=""></td>
      <td>نام فروشگاه</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="terminal_id"></td>
      <td>کد ترمينال</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="terminal_name"></td>
      <td>نام ترمينال</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="log_date" checked=""></td>
      <td>تاريخ ارسال</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="log_time" checked=""></td>
      <td>زمان ارسال</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="getpoint_date" checked=""></td>
      <td>تاريخ خريد</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="getpoint_time" checked=""></td>
      <td>زمان خريد</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="card_id" checked=""></td>
      <td>شماره کارت</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="name_pr"></td>
      <td>نام دارنده کارت</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="device_type"></td>
      <td>نوع پنل</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="amount" checked=""></td>
      <td>مبلغ</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="currency_" checked=""></td>
      <td>واحد</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="point_rate" checked=""></td>
      <td>ضريب لويالتی</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="point_lo" checked=""></td>
      <td>امتياز</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="doc_type" checked=""></td>
      <td>نوع پرداخت</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="cheque_num"></td>
      <td>شماره چک</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="cheque_date"></td>
      <td>تاريخ چک</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="account_number"></td>
      <td>شماره حساب</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bank_type"></td>
      <td>نام بانک</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="branch_code"></td>
      <td>شعبه</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="approval_code"></td>
      <td>کد خريد اعتباری</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="rebate_cons_per" checked=""></td>
      <td>درصد کارمزد </td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="special_discount"></td>
      <td>درصد تخفيف</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="pos_setup_rebate"></td>
      <td>درصد کارمزد بانی POS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="30">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bin_setup_rebate"></td>
      <td width="33%">درصد کارمزد پشتيبان</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="merch_setup_rebate"></td>
      <td width="33%">درصد کارمزد بازارياب</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="merch_setup"></td>
      <td width="33%">بازارياب</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="25">
      <td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="mer_id">
      </td>
      <td>کد فروشگاه</td>

      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bin_code">
      </td>
      <td>کد پشتيبان</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="rep_col" value="bin_name"></td>
      <td>نام پشتيبان</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$tds[2]` is a DOM node, not a jQuery object, so do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $trs = $('table > tbody > tr')
  // console.log('trs',$trs)

  var items = []
  for (var $i = 0; $i < $trs.length; ++$i) {
    $tds = $trs[$i].cells

    console.log('td', $($tds[2]).text())

    var item = {}
    item['label'] = ''
    item['flag'] = ''
    item['value'] = ''

  }

});
```

Answer (score -2):

You should wrap the `$tds[2]` in jquery like so: `$($tds[2])` in order to call `.text()` on it.

Here is example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$trs = $('table > tbody > tr')
// console.log('trs',$trs)

var items = []
for(var $i=0 ; $i < $trs.length ; ++$i){
    $tds = $trs[$i].cells

    console.log('td',$($tds[2]).text())

    var item        = {}
    item['label']   = ''
    item['flag']    = ''
    item['value']   = ''

}

});
```

Comment: He should use jQuery to get at the cells